Pointing a Django Project to my Purchased Domain in Google Cloud
I bought domain from GoDaddy and am hosting it in a bucket(which has the same name as my domain) in a project on Google cloud. In the bucket, under 'edit website configuration' I added a simple html page in the field called '
Index (main) page suffix'.  That html comes up correctly when I go to my domain on the browser.  So everthing works as expectd.
The problem is that I want to deploy a Django project(with several apps in it) to my domain instead of the simple html.  There are many tutorials that show how to deploy a Django project on Google Cloud but they all end up giving you a domain that they(or Google Cloud) assigns.  I don't want Google Cloud generated domain but want the project deployed on my purchased domain.
How do I make that work?  It seems like it shouldn't be hard so I'm guessing there is a simple 'trick' that I haven't been able to find.
I went through several tutorials on Django deployment on Google Cloud.  I even deployed one of the small examples from one tutorial.  But it has a Google Cloud generated domain name which is not what I want.

Depends on the product you want to use the configuration. There's a lot of doc for each one on how to set a custom domain. Which one are you using?

So you're using Cloud Run. I'd suggest to take the time to first understand what you're using and read all relevant documentation. The particular doc for setting a custom domain is in here https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains

@Puteri,
When I deploy with the following command:
gcloud run deploy polls-service.....
I get a message that looks like this:
Service [polls-service] revision [polls-service-00001-tug] has been deployed
and is serving 100 percent of traffic at [link](Google chosen url where my website is deployed)
The website works at their url perfectly.
But I want it to run on my purchased domain: mysite.com not Googles chosen url.
It have the DNS service with Cloudflare but am trying to host it on Google Cloud.  I bought the domain name from GoDaddy.

@Puteri,
I see where the document talks about maping from cloud.  That should tell me what I need to know.  Thank you.
